# Windows Authentication on IIS and Proxy to Node with User/Roles in Header?

Tags: node.js, iis, proxy, windows-authentication

I am running IIS and Node in parallel on a Windows Server. Is it possible to allow IIS intercept HTTPS requests, authentic them using Windows Authentication (Negotiate/NTLM), then proxy the requirements onto Node as HTTP requests with username and security groups in the header for Node to process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it is possible to use windows authentication before proxy request. Windows authentication is to authenticate people through the local Windows network. There is no proxy server or even a proxy server. Protocol does not authenticate HTTP sessions, but authenticates the underlying TCP connection.

IIS can also proxy the request to Node, as long as the request is rewritten using ARR and URL rewrite.

However, IIS itself cannot obtain the user name and security group information, and requires the help of ASP.NET applications.

Comment: It seems that I will need an ASP.NET application to get username and security groups then proxy to Node with headers.